# webdev select combobox and show result query sqlexec() in table

Tags: windev

hy i m working with webdev , i have combobox and table in my page , combobox have value of names of tables databse sql server ,i want  when i select value of combo show data of table in my table,  my table in project have 11 column but the tables i select from can be more or less

this is my code navigateur in select value from combo box :

```
projet is string =  Project.Valeur
res is array of string
//res = new array of nbrligne string
res = AJAXExécute(Get_project_label,projet)
i is int =1

// Process the received data
SI res <> Null ALORS
    Info("nbr ligne est = "+res.Occurrence())
    WHILE i <= res.Occurrence()
            TableAjoute(Table_label,res[i])
        i++
    FIN
ELSE
    Info("nbr ligne est null")
FIN
```

and this is my procedur with ajax activ:

```
PROCÉDURE Get_project_label(nameproject is string)
// open connexion to database
datalabel  is array of string
nbrligne is int =0
ConnectionNum is int = SQLConnect("*****", "******", "odbc_matrack", "*****", "OLEDB", hOledbSQLServer)
IF ConnectionNum <> 0 THEN
    // The connection was successful
    x is int = 1
    y is int = 1
    i is booléen = SQLExec("SELECT * FROM ["+nameproject+"]","qr")
    IF i THEN
        WHILE SQLFetch("qr") = 0 // There is still another line to read
        nbrligne++
        END
        SQLInfo()
        ResNbColl is int = SQL.NbCol
        datalabel = new array of nbrligne string
        WHILE x <= nbrligne// There is still another line to read
            WHILE y <= ResNbColl 
                datalabel[x] = SQLGetCol("qr",y)
                y++
            END
            x++
        END
        RETURN datalabel
    ELSE
        SQLInfo()
        Error("The query is failed." + CR + ...
        "Error code: " + SQL.Error + CR + SQL.MesError)
    END
    SQLClose("qr")
ELSE
    // The connection failed: display an error message
    SQLInfo()
    Error("The connection to the data source failed." + CR + ...
    "Error code: " + SQL.Error + CR + SQL.MesError)
END
// In any case (connection OK or not)
SQLDisconnect()
```

webdev when i select combobox show result in table from query sqlexec()